# The GraphQL type name, defined in the ContentSchemaProvider schema provider, begins with a lower-case character. Types must be Pascal Cased

Tags: graphql, serialization, scs

Environment:
**Sitecore 10.1.2
SCS Management Service package 5.1.25**

While setting up the Sitecore Content Serialization, I am facing this issue as the Type Name is in smaller case, needs to be in Pascal case.

[image]

Tried checking the Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.Master.config, but did not find any type name Any help will be appreciated.
Also decompiled the **Sitecore.Services.GraphQL**, and figured out

```
if (char.IsLetter(field.Name[0]) && char.IsUpper(field.Name[0]))
    throw new GraphQLSchemaValidationException("The " + field.Name + " field, defined on the " + type.Name + " type, defined in the " + type.GetSchemaProviderMetadata() + " schema provider, started with an upper case character. GraphQL fields are always camelCase.");
```

in the decompiled code.

But I am not able to find out the issue, where should I check
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you check the full config (/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx)?

Comment: Hi @Gatogordo, yeah I checked showconfig.aspx , but did not find anything else, please let me know what I need to search for.
I can see this in the config
<systemContent type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.ContentSchemaProvider, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">

Comment: You should check in the showconfig for any child of a ContentSchemaProvider that might have a type that is not correct.

Comment: Hi @Gatogordo yeah I checked but those all got installed with the Management service package only, and I am not sure of any such type issue

This is the immediate children of the ContentSchemaProvider
<templates type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content.TemplateGeneration.Filters.StandardTemplatePredicate, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Content">